# autotools: autoreconf can't find macro but aclocal can

Tags: macros, autotools, autoreconf

I'm trying to use autotools for the first time as a developer, so excuse any noobishness.

I'm using the [Check](http://check.sourceforge.net/) unit testing library which defines the macro `AM_PATH_CHECK` in `check.m4`, which was installed in `/usr/local/share/aclocal`.  I managed to get `aclocal` to recognize `AM_PATH_CHECK` by editing `/usr/share/aclocal/dirlist` to include `/usr/local/share/aclocal`.

So `aclocal` runs and returns cleanly (without any additional arguments).

However, when I run `autoreconf --install`, I get the error

```
configure.ac:36: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_CHECK
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow
      See the Autoconf documentation
autoreconf: /usr/local/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?  How should I let `autoreconf` know of the existence of `AM_PATH_LOCAL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had one of my peers help me out, and we discovered that the problem was that `pkg-config` wasn't installed.  (Evidently, not part of OSX's XCode tools).

I'm not sure who to file a bug with about this - should `Check` be checking for `pkg-confg` when it installs? Should `autoconf`?  Or is it so bog-standard that I should complain to the XCode tools people?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Check is installing itself incorrectly. You should file a bug there. What you can do to work around this problem is to add

`AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])`

to `configure.ac`, and add

`ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS += -I m4`

to `Makefile.am`, and then copy `check.m4` to the `m4` directory that will be created in your project's root directory.

Comment: Check may be the issue.  I tried your fix, and got the same error though.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it.  Thanks, though.